# Testing with mocks and without Mocks, time of tests

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I am learning TDD and I have some doubts when usings Mocks with mockito and junit.

```
Without mocks:   
Contacto contacto = new Contacto("Santiago", "3022653192", "santi-1524@hotmail.com");
        agenda.agregarContacto(contacto);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, agenda.getSizeOfAgenda());
        agenda.agregarContacto(contacto);
With mocks:
        Mockito.verify(agenda).agregarContacto(contacto);
        Mockito.when(agenda.getSizeOfAgenda()).thenReturn(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, agenda.getSizeOfAgenda());
```

if I do the test without the mocks it takes less time than doing the test with Test for example: 2ms vs 356ms.

what are the benefits of doing the test with Mockito in this case?

Comment: junit mocking is useful to mock external dependencies but not the internal logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of missing the point of mocking. You use mocks to ensure ( mock ) the behavior of the surrounding services  / external dependencies and everything that do not have to do directly with what you want to test.

In your example if you test your agenda service you will mock the contact as its irrelevant what contents it has as long as a `contact` goes in the `agenda`. If you also had lets say a `calendar` in the `agenda` you would mock that `calendar` also.

> what are the benefits of doing the test with Mockito in this case?

In your case mocking was used in the wrong way. 
A clear example of why you want to mock is a Service that will save something to your database.

```java
public class SomeService {
  private SomeRepository repo;
  public SomeService(SomeRepository repo){
    this.repo = repo;
  }
  public YourClass save(YourClass clazz){
    repo.save(clazz);
  }
}

public class SomeRepository {
  private Connection yourDatabaseConnection;

  public YourClass save(YourClass clazz){
    yourDatabaseConnection.save(clazz);
  }
}
```

So lets not bother how the connection is setup. When you will run a test from `SomeService` this will call your repo thus saving something in your database. Meaning you will have to setup a database and take care of the data inside which may create problems if you run multiple tests or tests in parallel ( if you and one of your colleges run the same test with you at the same time ). All this is a fuss and goes outside the unit-testing theory. Your unit is the Service in this scenario the `SomeService`. So you only need to test this.

```java
@Test
public void test(){
  final SomeRepository repo = mock(SomeRepository.class);
  final SomeService serv = new SomeService(repo);

  final YourClass clazz = mock(YourClass.class);

  when(repo.save(clazz)).thenReturn(clazz);

  YourClass response = serv.save(clazz);

  Assert.assertEquals(clazz,response);

  verify(repo).save(clazz);
}
```

This way you validate your service returns your object without any mutations in the middle as this was the expected behavior from the setup above. You validate it called the repository but you never actually calling it. This way no data will be added in your database ( meaning you dont need a database ) and the test is isolated and can be run in parallel a million times and it always have the same result.